# Core temperature above threshold but sensors says temperatures are far way from critical

Tags: fan, overheating, xps, temperature

I own an XPS 9370 and often find the following in my `dmesg`

```
[40705.581409] mce: CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 950)
[40705.581410] mce: CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 950)
[40705.581411] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581412] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581413] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581414] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581445] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581446] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581447] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.581448] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3843)
[40705.585426] mce: CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[40705.585428] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585428] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585429] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585430] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585431] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585431] mce: CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[40705.585432] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585433] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[40705.585434] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.582396] mce: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1547)
[41528.582397] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1547)
[41528.582398] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582399] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582400] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582400] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582403] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582407] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582416] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.582417] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4112)
[41528.585420] mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[41528.585420] mce: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
[41528.585421] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585422] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585423] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585442] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585443] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585444] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585445] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[41528.585445] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.738360] mce: CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 977)
[42028.738360] mce: CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 977)
[42028.738384] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738387] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738389] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738389] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738390] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738391] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738393] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.738393] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4144)
[42028.739359] mce: CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[42028.739359] mce: CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[42028.739360] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739360] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739391] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739391] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739393] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739393] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739394] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[42028.739394] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.286406] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1589)
[42366.286407] mce: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1589)
[42366.286408] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286409] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286411] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286412] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286413] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286414] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286415] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.286417] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4194)
[42366.289376] mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[42366.289377] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289378] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289379] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289379] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289380] mce: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
[42366.289381] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289381] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289382] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[42366.289383] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
```

But at the same time, `sensors` returns the following at the same moment when I get those logs

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +55.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +53.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +47.5°C
```

which is far away from critical temperatures.
Can somebody clear this up fro me?

Edit:
Added the `turbostat` startup information

```
turbostat version 18.07.27 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x16 CPUID levels; 0x80000008 xlevels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8e:a (6:142:10)
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR - EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, EPB
cpu6: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): SGX
cpu6: MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00040005 (Locked SGX)
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 166 ecx_crystal_hz: 0
TSC: 1992 MHz (24000000 Hz * 166 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 2000 max_mhz: 4000 bus_mhz: 100
cpu6: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00401cc0 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 17476 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 15 Watts
cpu6: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x4043df1011400
4 * 100.0 = 400.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
20 * 100.0 = 2000.0 MHz base frequency
cpu6: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x0024005d (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu6: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x25252828
37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
40 * 100.0 = 4000.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
40 * 100.0 = 4000.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x00000012 (base_ratio=18)
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x00080050 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL1=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL1=0 LVL1_RATIO=8 PKG_TDP_LVL1=80)
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x001400c8 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL2=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL2=0 LVL2_RATIO=20 PKG_TDP_LVL2=200)
cpu6: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x00000000 ( lock=0)
cpu6: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000011 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=17 lock=0)
cpu6: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x1e008008 (UNdemote-C3, UNdemote-C1, demote-C3, demote-C1, locked, pkg-cstate-limit=8 (unlimited))
cpu6: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu6: cpufreq governor: powersave
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu6: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x01081228 (high 40 guar 18 eff 8 low 1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x80002804 (min 4 max 40 des 0 epp 0x80 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000000 (Dis_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000000 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, No-Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: 0x00000006 (balanced)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x00000078 (15 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x420198009c80d8 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (27.000000 Watts, 24.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: DISabled (51.000000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x5400de00140000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 1.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: GFX Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x02640000 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x8828080a (60 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (100 C, 100 C)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x0000884e (valid, 79872 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00008876 (valid, 120832 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00008894 (valid, 151552 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x000088fa (valid, 256000 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x0000894c (valid, 339968 ns)
cpu6: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00008bf2 (valid, 1034240 ns)
```

Edit2: Added `stress` test
[image: Stress test]

Comment: Because I see "mce" there must be something else going on at the same time. Review /var/log/syslog* and see if you can find something around the time of the mce or temp messages.

Comment: There is only a few milliseconds between the throttling and the return to normal temps, `sensors` is not going to catch that.

Comment: If I understand correctly your computer has an 8th gen Intel i7 processor. So, I would use turbostat to monitor the processor package temperature: `sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 5`. Also without the `--quiet` option will add a big spew of stuff at startup that might (or might not) indicate if some thresholds have been changed and what the overall power budget is.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for the hint. Sadly, I can not read anything out of it which seems related...

Comment: @rtaft Sure. But the sensors command was executed a few seconds after the dmesg output appeared, and the hardware would normally need some time to cool down, right?

Comment: @DougSmythies Yes, that's correct. I added the startup output (without --quiet) to the OP. Can you read something out of it?

Comment: re: syslog... try this... it may generate quite a lot of output, so post it at paste.ubuntu.com... `grep -i mce -B 10 -A 10 /var/log/syslog*`

Comment: @heynnema Sure https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hnsjDnT6Nh/

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost not necessarily.  For instance, I ran `stress --cpu 8` in one terminal and `sensors` in another.  By the time I stop `stress`, switch to the other terminal and run `sensors` the temp has dropped from 60C to 33C...though it's not a laptop.  My laptop drops from 60C to 50C when I do that.

Comment: @rtaft Seems like you are correct. Just starting stress instantly brings my CPU to 96°C due to turbostat and cools down fast afterwerwards.
But it's interesting that sensors always reports about 10°C less...

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost It's the biggest pain when trying to run a quiet system, the fans kick on thinking the system is hot when the cooling system is sitting at 33C

Comment: I've reviewed the lengthy syslog output. A couple of things catch my eye. Do you have **Evince** (Document Viewer) running all of the time? `grep -i evince /var/log/syslog*` will show you what I'm seeing. GNOME extension **workspacesViews** is having a problem. `grep -i workspacesViews /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: Lets check your BIOS. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` will show your current version. Then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, because I write my bachelor thesis atm.
 I'm aware of the second issue, it's already fixed upstream https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1266 but not yet ported.
Furthermore, BIOS is up to date.

Comment: Try quitting Document Viewer for a little while, and see if you get cpu temp warnings when it's not running.

Comment: @heynnema Alright, I'll give it a try.

Comment: It seems to me same problem has been reported by one or two other users here.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix same problem as the OP, or same problem with Document Viewer?

Comment: @heynnema Others have been reporting false temperature readings lately.

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost Did my answer provide a solution? Status please.

Comment: Low TDP for this processor. `sensors` looks O.K. to me, just that the sample was, perhaps, taken after the throttling already settled to 84-85 degrees. Suggest a thermald profile that kicks in at a lower trip point, or limit highest CPU frequency via `echo 60 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`, for example.

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost status please

Comment: @heynnema Sadly, it seems like it is not evince. I didn't open evince yesterday and today but my log is still full of the temperature warnings.

Comment: @DougSmythies Do I understand your answer correctly, that that would limit my CPU frequency to 60%?

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : Yes. Experiment further to find whatever limit prevents the overheat.

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost I'd keep `htop` running in a terminal window, and run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in another terminal window, and as soon as you see syslog showing temp errors, look at htop to see if there's a process using high cpu time at the same time.